# Put an image with transparent background into a pdf using Libharu

Tags: pdf, png, libpng, libharu

I have to put an image (.png) into a pdf file using ***LibHaru***. The image has a transparent background due to which it looks quite awkward (black background) into the pdf file.

How can I put this image (with transparent background) properly using C++ LibHaru?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your PNG file into two images: one for color pixels and another one for opacity values. Then you need to add the color image into PDF with specifying the second as SMASK property.

See **4.8.4 Image Dictionaries** in PDF specification for more details.

You can use **[HPDF_Image_AddSMask](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/blob/d84867ebf9f3de6afd661d2cdaff102457fbc371/src/hpdf_image.c#L622)** method for this.